# Incollection entry with separate years for book and chapter

Tags: biblatex

I want to cite a chapter in a book, hence I think I should use `incollection`. However I would need to specify two years:

- one for the year the book was published
- one for the year the chapter was written

The entry should look somewhat like this:

Esping-Andersen, Gøsta (1990). „Three Worlds of Welfare Capitalism“. In: *The Welfare State Reader*. Hrsg. von Christopher Pierson, Francis G. Castles und Ingela K. Naumann. 2. Aufl. Cambridge: Polity Press 2006, S. 160–174.

Is there a way to do this with BibLaTex?

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib} 
@incollection{esping-andersen_three_2006,
    location = {Cambridge},
    edition = {2},
    title = {Three Worlds of Welfare Capitalism},
    pages = {160--174},
    booktitle = {The Welfare State Reader},
    publisher = {Polity Press},
    author = {Esping-Andersen, Gøsta},
    editor = {Pierson, Christopher and Castles, Francis G. and Naumann, Ingela K.},
    year = {2006}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper, german, oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, firstinits=false]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{test.bib}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is also `inbook`, which might be jut an alias. I haven't checked. Does it by coincidence give the respected result?

Comment: There is no standard way of doing that. In order to achieve this we have to modify the bibliography style you use. So please post an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that shows what bibliography style you intend on using and other modifications to `biblatex`.

Comment: You should keep in mind though that the bibliography is for finding references. Since you used the collection version of the paper in its 2006 version this is what you cite. The fact that the original paper was published in 1990 is a nice aside, but knowledge of this particular detail does not really influence the reader's ability to find the very version of the article you cited.

Comment: @Johannes_B `@inbook` and `@incollection` are not aliased in the standard styles (and probably in most other styles). A `@book` is a work where the authors share credit for the work in its entirety. `@collection`s on the other hand, consist of separate contributions by distinct authors and the whole work often does not have authors, but editors. In this case here it, seems pretty clear to me that `@incollection` is the right entry type here.

Comment: @moewe Fairy point, i think you are right.

Comment: @moewe I included a MWE. Also: fair point about what a reference is for. For this particular case it is not very important, but I'd like to be able to cite it "completely" for future cases.

Comment: Thanks for the MWE! Can I take away from your presentation that you would like to cite the work as "Esping-Andersen 1990"?

Comment: @moewe yes. Citing it as _Esping-Andersen 2006_ as you proposed would be a good solution as well, still: sometimes there is a chapter in a book which was originally published somewhere else and I would like to be able to cite at least the year more clearly.

Comment: Generally, you should cite the original publication and not an anthologised version. So you almost certainly shouldn't be trying to do this at all. There are exceptions in which a reprint has become the standard (perhaps because the original is difficult to obtain), but then the relevant publication year is the reprint year.

Comment: @cfr My understanding is that one should always cite the version of the work one actually worked with (read etc.). (If only to make sure that page references line up. Leaving aside the ethical and practical implications of claiming to have read something one has not actually seen.) In most cases, it is desirable to work with the original publication, however, I would think. (So my comment was totally pointless if by "cite" you also meant *read* and *work with*.)

Comment: @moewe I meant at least *work with* in the sense that you might read a reprint initially, but then you'd get the original for checking purposes when citing. So, certainly, the page numbers should match but, also, you'd check that the reprint hadn't incorporated changes not present in the original. If you cannot get hold of the original, then you certainly cannot use it for citation purposes. (You can say that the version you use is a reprint of... but you can't cite it as as source you've used.) I think we are in agreement and I just didn't put the point very clearly - sorry about that.

Comment: @cfr Indeed, we seem to agree. There is no need to apologise, when I read your comment for the second time I had a hunch you meant *work with* rather than citing. `:-)` And the modus operandi you suggest seems to me at least to be best practice with regards to original works and reprint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{origdate.bib}
@incollection{esping-andersen_three_2006,
location = {Cambridge},
edition = {2},
title = {Three Worlds of Welfare Capitalism},
pages = {160--174},
booktitle = {The Welfare State Reader},
publisher = {Polity Press},
author = {Esping-Andersen, Gøsta},
editor = {Pierson, Christopher and Castles, Francis G. and Naumann, Ingela K.},
year = {2006},
origdate = {1990}
}
%
@inbook{esping-andersen_2008,
location = {Oxford},
title = {Three Worlds of Welfare Capitalism},
pages = {160--174},
booktitle = {The Welfare State Reader},
publisher = {Polity Press},
author = {Esping-Andersen, Gøsta},
editor = {Pierson, Christopher and Castles, Francis G. and Naumann, Ingela K.},
year = {2008}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper, german, oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, firstinits=false, labeldate]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{origdate.bib}

\DeclareLabeldate{%
\field{origdate}
\field{date}
\field{eventdate}
\field{urldate}
\literal{nodate}
}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
\printlist{location}%
\iflistundef{publisher}
{\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
{\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
\printlist{publisher}%
\setunit*{\addspace}%
\iffieldsequal{labelyear}{year}{%
\usebibmacro{date}}{\printdate}
\newunit}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If at all possible, with some exceptions, you should use the original publication as your source and cite accordingly. If, for some reason, that just isn't possible, I would use `biblatex`'s `related` facilities. In this case, your citations will show that you are using the 2006 version, which is true, but your bibliography will also show that this is a reprint and what it is a reprint of.

For example:

[image: related entries]

[Note that I'm assuming the German says something appropriate although I cannot tell.]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{esping-andersen_three_2006,
    location = {Cambridge},
    edition = {2},
    title = {Three Worlds of Welfare Capitalism},
    pages = {160--174},
    booktitle = {The Welfare State Reader},
    publisher = {Polity Press},
    author = {Esping-Andersen, Gøsta},
    editor = {Pierson, Christopher and Castles, Francis G. and Naumann, Ingela K.},
    year = {2006},
    related = {esping-andersen_three_1990},
    relatedtype = {reprintof}
}
@article{esping-andersen_three_1990,
    title = {Three Worlds of Welfare Capitalism},
    pages = {213--265},
    journal = {Some Journal},
    author = {Esping-Andersen, Gøsta},
    year = 1990,
    volume = 63,
    number = 2
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper, german, oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, firstinits=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's me again, sorry `;-)`. I would prefer the original not to appear as a bibliography entry on its own (maybe via `options = {dataonly},` in `esping-andersen_three_1990`). Note that in this set-up the `related` entry does not display the date of the reprinted entry (I'm sure there is a modification to do that). Your assumption about the German text is spot on.

Comment: The solution to printing the year of the related entry lies in `{related:default}`. By default only the bibmacro `date` is restored, but `issue+date` remains in its reduced state of only printing the `issue` thanks to the `mergedate` setting. The solution is restoring the `issue+date` macro to its original state as in `standard.bbx` via the pre-code hook of `\usedriver`.

Comment: @moewe Is this because the original is an article (as I've written it)? When I use this myself with books, I get the date in the entry and no separate entry.

Comment: I suppose so. `@article`s use the `issue+date` macro to print the date (this macro is a wrapper around `\usebibmacro{date}` and also prints the issue; it is modified by some `mergedate` options - including the default - to only print the `issue`, because it is assumed the year was printed after the author) this macro is not restored by `related:deafult` while `date` (which is used in a way by `@book`s that mergedate does not interfere with if `date` is restored) is restored.

Comment: I just realised my "explanation" above was a bit nebulous. With `authoryear`-like styles the date is moved right after the author, the exact nature of this arrangement is controlled by the `mergedate` option. The `mergedate`s redefine 3 bibmacros `date+extrayear`, `date` and `issue+date` (the latter is only used by `@article`s/`@periodical`s). In `related:default` where the moving around of `date`s is probably not desired, those macros are restored if need be with the exception of `issue+date`. But because `issue+date` is not restored to print the date, `@article`s lack the year in this setup.

Comment: The original article appeared thanks to the `\nocite{*}`, if we have `options = {dataonly}` we can make sure that that cannot happen. In "normal" documents you might not have `\nocite{*}` and thus are not affected by that behaviour.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, that makes sense. Of course, I'd forgotten about the `\nocite{*}`. I suspect [Bernard's solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239437/) is the most sensible one in this case, unless the OP has a lot of cases like this one. Still, it seems to me that it would be better if the `authoryear` style did not do this in cases where the years differ!

Comment: Definitely. Maybe it was an oversight when coding the `related:default` macro. The `authoryear` mergedate issue might have been forgotten there. Or maybe it was left because restoring the `issue+date` macro would have taken quite some lines of code.